# What is the prefered way of updating 'created' and 'updated' columns? Via triggers or via the software?

Tags: java, database, triggers

I was wondering what people prefer when fields like 'created' and 'modified' have to be changed? Is it prefered to do this in the application code or use triggers for that??

Answer (score 3):

Both are valid, but my experience is that it's more common to do it in code. I tend to put it in the application code.

- Often you want to be able to cross-reference these timestamps with various logging information. Doing it in code ensures that the timestamps line up. Otherwise, you add an extra maintenance load to always ensure that the system time on your db-servers and app-servers are in sync
- Logic today tends to be more in the application than in the database. Stored procedures and the likes are less and less utilized, especially in systems being built from scratch. Therefore, less and less notice is taken of the database so putting logic in triggers tend to get forgotten over time and it makes it harder to debug your application as logic will pass across process (and technology) boundaries.
- Sometimes triggers don't fire. Many people will claim that they are fool-proof, but I've seen them fail more than once. And it has forever tainted my opinion of them.

Proper design and usage of AOP and framework support will let you do this fairly unobtrusively and with minimal copy/paste boiler-plate code.

Comment: +1; you may want to add the fact that triggers may not know the end user, especially when it comes to applications accessing the DB via connection pools. In my experience it's not only about `created` and ` updated` but also about the user (who updated the record)...

Comment: Indeed a very valid reason to use application based modification of these attributes, thanks for pointing me out!

Answer (score 1):

Doing it via triggers would have been preferred if every database supported triggers on Insert and Update. But that is not the case with all the databases. Your Java code should be database agnostic as much as possible and code should not assume dependency on particular database(s) hence it is better to have some layer/interceptor between your application code and database to do this for you. That way you can avoid repetitive code and keep business logic clean from these update calls.

Comment: +1 for mentioning lack of support in many databases. Oftentimes, you'll run different databases for dev and prod (Oracle in prod, HSQLDB for dev and integration test).

Comment: Not all the applications require to be database-agnostic. It's cost-effective sometimes to drop support of certain databases, if you gain features and reduce complexity.

Comment: The fact that it reduces complexity is indeed one of the reasons that i brought up this topic. We are using MyBatis as mapping framework and this is hookedup into a Spring based application. So their should be a more or less AOP like way to let the application manage this. But this indeed introduces another layer off complexity. Is has the big advantage that i do not have to worry about it on application level. We are planning to use MySQL as database. We also have our GUID generation inside triggers. So when saving a record GUID and timestamps are generated and stored.

Comment: Normally i would handle this in the application but as stated, we like to bring down the level of complexity. We are not sure yet if we need to migrate to another DB.

Comment: I have also started my answer with my preference to do it via triggers. But I have also experienced few instances when database independence is needed and there were cases when back end database was changed, so take your call as per your situation.